# How to set OutlineButton width > child width and the border expand to all available space?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a custom button like this:

```dart
class ControlButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final void Function() onPressed;
  final double width;
  final double height;

  ControlButton({
    @required this.text,
    @required this.onPressed,
    this.width = 90.0,
    this.height = 40.0,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: OutlineButton(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: _orangeColor),
        onPressed: onPressed,
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(color: _orangeColor),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and use this button like this:

```
          ControlButton(
            text: 'Hold on',
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
```

when I try to set the width < child width, the left, and right border become closer and the text inside was expanded to 2 lines.
But when I try to set the width > child width, there are unused spaces at both side of the button, the border still stays the same when I set width = child width.

Is there any way that I could set the width > child width and the button border expands to all available space?

Comment: I recently fixed a bug that prevents buttons from growing as wide as they can, this may only be in the master branch currently.

Comment: @JonahWilliams Thanks, I'm using dev channel. I will try switching to master to see if this is fixed yet.

Comment: Wow, it works as expected. Thank you. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually a bug and anyone facing this issue please switch to the master channel with flutter > v0.5.8-pre.141